# How can I create Redisson Client to connect to a redis

Tags: java, reddison

I am not sure how to create a RedissonClient object in the application.
1- Should this object be created for every transaction or
2- The object should singleton per JVM?
3- Only one object for all the services?

Currently, my setup is an embedded Jetty with Jersey APIs for 3 Services running on a different set of Kubernetes pods and Redis setup is 3 + 3 master and slave config.

Current config looks like this.

public class RedisTemplate {

```
public static final RedissonClient REDISCLIENT;
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(RedisTemplate.class);

public static final String redisMaster = "redis-cluster";

static {
    Config config = new Config();

    logger.info("redis config for server");

    config.useClusterServers().addNodeAddress("redis://" + redisMaster + ":6379");

    REDISCLIENT = Redisson.create(config);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in their [FAQ](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/16.-FAQ#q-when-do-i-need-to-shut-down-a-redisson-instance-at-the-end-of-each-request-or-the-end-of-the-life-of-a-thread), redisson should be singleton:

> **Q: When do I need to shut down a Redisson instance, at the end of each request or the end of the life of a thread?**
>   **A** : Redisson instance requires manual shutdown only if you want to stop using all of its features. It is a common pattern that Redisson starts and stops along with the application. Since it is completely thread safe, you may treat a Redisson instance as a singleton. The shutdown sequence will disconnect all the active connections held in each connection pool, and it will clean up certain types of Redisson objects require a manual destroy action upon disposal, it will then stop the event loops. Please be advised, the entire shutdown process is not instant.